# Itext PdfImportedPage adding margins to the page

Tags: pdf, itext

itext version being used is : 2.1.7

Please see the code below (the else condition), it rotates the landscaped page and while rotating, scales it. The scaling works fine, but I am trying to add margin at the bottom of the page (line 25 and 26) which doesn't seem to have any effect. What am I doing wrong?

```
            Rectangle currentPageSize = reader.getPageSize(currentPageNumber);
            
            logger.debug("Height for current page: " + currentPageSize.getHeight() + ", width of page: " + currentPageSize.getWidth());
            
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, currentPageNumber++);
            
            if ( currentPageSize.getHeight() > currentPageSize.getWidth() ) {               
            
                cb.addTemplate(page, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 30); 
                
            } else {
                logger.debug("page height: "+page.getHeight());
                logger.debug("page width: "+page.getWidth());

                //Find the scale
                float scale = PageSize.A4.getHeight()/page.getWidth() ;
                logger.debug("scale: "+scale);

                final AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
                at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90)));
                at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale));
                double[] matrix = new double[6];
                at.getMatrix(matrix);
                
                Rectangle rect = page.getBoundingBox();
                rect.setBorderWidthBottom(10);
                logger.debug("Rotation and scale matrix for A4 page: "+ Arrays.toString(matrix));
                cb.addTemplate(page, (float) matrix[0], (float) matrix[1], (float) matrix[2],
                               (float) matrix[3], currentPageSize.getHeight() * scale, (float) matrix[5]);
                               
            }
```